# How do I create a box image which contains a photo and text?

Tags: text, images

I'd like to create boxes just like what's shown in the following link, using images of hair colour which are jpeg's and bmp's. Is it something fairly simple that I could do on my Mac? Many thanks.

https://cysterwigs.com/pages/colors-101-your-color-cheat-sheet

Comment: It is, and *any* basic drawing program worth its storage space should be able to do it. Pick one and try.

Comment: In fact you do not even need any specific program, all you need is  a text editor (all OS:es ship one). And you wan directly write the EPS or use SVG and a browser for example

Answer (score 1):

As commented, take a drawing program and try. Freeware goes well. Here is an example. Its made with Inkscape.

In the left there are the parts: the JPG photo, a white box, darker blurred box as the shadow and the text. In the right all parts are stacked to final order and aligned. The background is not defined in this phase.

[image]

If you have a ready photo to import, the rest is done in a minute. Inkscape is not a photo editor. You need it separately. In Inkscape one easily draws boxes, lines, curves and texts. For photos there are no advanced editing tools, but scaling, cropping and brightness & contrast adjustments go well.